# LocateRegistry.createRegistry

Tags: java, rmi

I need an RMI registry that makes the service accessible from outside my machine, while still being able to refuse a connection based on the IP of the client. The following code makes the registry only accessible from my machine, but never gets into the "RMIClientSocketFactory" code:

```
LocateRegistry.createRegistry(uri.getPort(), new RMIClientSocketFactory() {
            @Override
            public Socket createSocket(String host, int port) throws IOException {
                System.out.println("RMIServerSocketFactory().createSocket()");
                InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName(host);
                if (addr.equals(InetAddress.getLocalHost())) {
                    return new Socket(addr, port);
                } else {
                    throw new IOException("remote socket bind forbidden.");
                }
            }
        }, new RMIServerSocketFactory() {
            @Override
            public ServerSocket createServerSocket(int port) throws IOException {
                System.out.println("RMIServerSocketFactory().createServerSocket()");
                return new ServerSocket(port, 0, InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1"));
            }
        });
```

So it runs "RMIServerSocketFactory" and binds on the loopback, but never verifies the client IP.
Any help is welcome, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The client socket factory is not what you need.

What you need is the `ServerSocket` to reject connections from unwanted IPs. The easiest way to achieve this is to create a subclass of `ServerSocket` which overrides the `accept()` method to immediately close connections from unwanted IPs and throw an exception.

However there are better, low level ways to control network access, I don't think your application doubling as a firewall (which is essentially what you need) is a particularly good idea.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! Is it just me or is implAccept marked final? Could you please add some more information? Thanks !

Comment: @iDemmel You're right, I misunderstood the documentation, it's `accept()` that you should override.

Comment: public Socket accept() throws IOException {
                            while (true) {
                                Socket socket = super.accept();
                                String ip = socket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress();
                                if (ip.equals("192.168.2.246") || ip.equals("127.0.0.1")) {
                                    return socket;
                                }
                                socket.close();
                            }
                        }

Comment: @iDemmel I think you should check the remote address instead (`Socket.getRemoteAddress()`), otherwise it seems okay.

Comment: It is the remote address:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#getInetAddress()
It works, I just want to know if it's a decent implementation. I don't know how to give the client a decent message though, it's just an EOFException now when I close the socket ;)
Thank you for your help!

Comment: @iDemmel Well, normally, that is, if this was handled by a firewall, you wouldn't even accept the connection attempt. So bear in mind that this solution is not very good if you want strong security, easpecially if your server is facing the internet.. But if you don't want that, closing the socket will do: every client should be able to handle an abrupt disconnection.