# How do I create a rmi server that will accept only one connection at a time?

Tags: java, rmi

I'm writing a client-server pair in java using rmi java. I want the server to listen for a connection, and while one client is connected the server should reject any other clients that try to connect.

Comment: Why you want to limit the server performance?

Comment: Because if I use more client the traffic between client & server may increase because whatever client send to server it must be re transmitted to other client and I tried it but my server fail to  response .

Answer (score 2):

You would need to start the RMI registry in code using http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/rmi/registry/LocateRegistry.html#createRegistry%28int,%20java.rmi.server.RMIClientSocketFactory,%20java.rmi.server.RMIServerSocketFactory%29, and write a custom [RMIServerSocketFactory](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/rmi/server/RMIServerSocketFactory.html) that returns a ServerSocket that only accepts a single connection.

EDIT: with a mashup of [LocateRegistry.createRegistry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263904/rmi-locateregistry-createregistry) and http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/rmi/hello/Server.java with a little extra code thrown in (note that I didn't compile this, so you will need to sort out any compile errors yourself; it is intended to show you the general usage):

EDIT 2: fixed it to incorporate @EJP's suggestion (for more detail see [this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/socketfactory/index.html#1)).

```
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;

public class Server implements Hello {

    public Server() {}

    public String sayHello() {
    return "Hello, world!";
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

    try {
        Server obj = new Server();
        RMIClientSocketFactory csf = new RMIClientSocketFactory() {
            @Override
            public Socket createSocket(String host, int port) throws IOException {
                InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName(host);
                if (addr.equals(InetAddress.getLocalHost())) {
                    return new Socket(addr, port);
                } else {
                    throw new IOException("remote socket bind forbidden.");
                }
            }
        };
        RMIServerSocketFactory ssf = new RMIServerSocketFactory() {
            @Override
            public ServerSocket createServerSocket(int port) throws IOException {
                System.out.println("RMIServerSocketFactory().createServerSocket()");
                return new ServerSocket(port, 1, InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1"));
            }
        };
        Hello stub = (Hello) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(obj, 0, csf, ssf);

        // Bind the remote object's stub in the registry
        Registry registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(uri.getPort(), csf, ssf);

        registry.bind("Hello", stub);

        System.err.println("Server ready");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Server exception: " + e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can use give simple.example pls.

Comment: All that does, not very well, is restrict concurrent connections to the Registry. Not what he asked for. The backlog of 1 will be raised to at least 50 on modern operating systems. Throwing the exception on 'remote socket bind' is completely redundant: the Registry already detects that.

Comment: From the question: **I want the server to listen for a connection, and while one client is connected the server should reject any other clients that try to connect.** I may have my RMI wrong, but isn't the registry the way connections are managed, and if the registry only accepts a single connection doesn't that reject all other connections? He didn't say **I only want one client executing at a time**, he said **I only want one client connecting at a time**.

Comment: @Femi you are assuming the client will look up the Registry before doing every remote method call. It doesn't have to do that once it has the stub from the first lookup.

Comment: @EJP: very good point. I've updated my implementation to cover that situation.

Comment: @Femi that still leaves two other problems, one of which is fatal. A backlog of 1 will be raised to the platform minimum which is at least 50 on modern operating systems, and to my knowledge has never been less than 5. Your solution does not work.

Comment: Interesting. Backlog appears to be largely advisory. I'm not at my desk so I can't code it up but I should think one could override the server socket's methods to track the number of connections and reject any new connections if there are any current connections.

Comment: @Femi Backlog is not 'advisory', it is a feature built into the TCP/IP stack. You cannot lower it below the platform minimum, which is at least 50, more like 50 or 500 these days. No amount of overriding will change the fact that the TCP/IP can accept up that many connections before any of your code even executes. Nothing you have posted here answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

One simple home-grown approach would be to pass everything through a single method which keeps track of the number of requesting threads. If there is already a requesting thread in progress, an exception can be thrown. Otherwise, the requesting thread is allowed to proceed.

Some code to illustrate the concept but not necessarily an implementation ...

```
public class RequestHandler {

    private boolean activeRequest = false;


    public void handeRequest() throws Exception {
         synchronized(this) {
             if (activeRequest) {
                throw new Exception("Request in progress");
             }
             else {
                 activeRequest = true;
             }
         }

         // delegate to something else to perform the request logic


         synchronized(this) {
            activeRequest = false;
         }
    }
```

}

Comment: Thanks but what happen when if client crash or client's computer restart suddenly.....because I think it remain true if clinet doesn't properly disconnect with server...........sorry if I am worng.

Comment: The client and server are separate processes, so the server thread would continue to execute the handleRequest method even if the client machine/process went down in the meantime.

Comment: Talk about doing it the hard way ;-(

Comment: @EJP - a synchronized remote method prevents multiple server threads from concurrently executing the same method, but it does not "reject" any other clients attempting to connect. I was not alone in this interpretation of what needed to be done. Indeed it is harder when you solve the posted problem, rather than a different one.

Comment: @breat *nothing* rejects another client trying to connect. The TCP backlog makes this completely infeasible.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do here is declare your remote method(s) as synchronized. Then only one client can enter it/them at a time.